# Aptana 3 - Can't update because of pydev dependency

Tags: aptana3

I'm trying without success to update aptana 3 using the Check for updates.. option, but I am getting the following error:

Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Aptana Studio 3 3.0.7.201112151935-15122011194114 (com.aptana.rcp.product 3.0.7.201112151935-15122011194114)
  Software currently installed: Shared profile 1.0.0.1313016179000 (SharedProfile_AptanaProfile 1.0.0.1313016179000)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Pydev debug 2.2.1.2011073123 (org.python.pydev.debug 2.2.1.2011073123)
    Pydev debug 2.2.4.2011121401 (org.python.pydev.debug 2.2.4.2011121401)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Shared profile 1.0.0.1313016179000 (SharedProfile_AptanaProfile 1.0.0.1313016179000)
    To: org.python.pydev.debug [2.2.1.2011073123]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Aptana Studio 3 3.0.7.201112151935-15122011194114 (com.aptana.rcp.product 3.0.7.201112151935-15122011194114)
    To: org.python.pydev.debug [2.2.4.2011121401]

How to I uninstall pydev / solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you've installed PyDev, you really need to uninstall it to get Aptana Studio 3 (which already contains a version of PyDev) -- go to help > about > installation details, click the PyDev plugin and select "uninstall" (at the bottom).

Also, instead of doing 'check for updated', I'd recommend going to help > install new software, deselect 'contact all update sites to find required software' and then entering the Aptana Studio 3 Update site (as a new version will be there, it'll go on and only update Aptana Studio 3 at that point).

Comment: Hi Fabio, thanks for your response. When I go to help > about > installation details there is no listing for pydev unless I click on the Aptana installation and when I click on the PyDev plugin under that the uninstall option does not become available but just stays greyed out. Any ideas?

Comment: Strange... it seems you have PyDev installed standalone and Eclipse does not recognize it? Have you tried just going to the path of the install new software I put above (without doing the uninstall)?

Comment: Yeah perhaps that is what is happening, I have no idea how to fix it, I've uninstalled all of the other plugins apart from the Aptana 3 plugins which I can't uninstall and I still get the pydev dependency conflict. I tried your other method and unfortunately it just says: Your original request has been modified.
  Aptana Studio 3 will be ignored because it is already installed, and updates are not permitted etc.

Comment: If I re-install will I lose my project references?

Comment: No, as long as you point to the same workspace (i.e.: all the information from your project is kept on the workspace and not in the eclipse install)

Comment: Ok I guess that's the only way I can resolve this issue then. Thanks for your help I'll mark this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

I know what the problem may be not working because the python interpreter path is not defined, after installing Aptana 3 you go to menu Window / Preferences and the option Interpreter - Python using the Auto Config button, good luck